# $_FILE passes file from JS to PHP script with 0 bytes (using jQuery validate v1.14.0 and jQuery v3.2.1)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a webform that allows user's to select up to 4 files to submit to our server.

On submit, jQuery validation (v1.14.0) only checks that the file exists and is less that 3MB - it does not check if the file is greater than 0 bytes (*** First error ***).

Therefore, if a user was to upload a file of 0 bytes the data would pass the front end validation and proceed to the PHP script.

However, its highly unlikely that the user has actually attempted to upload a file of 0 bytes. For example, here is the $_FILE contents of a recent user's submission prior to any PHP processing:

```
{
    "fileOne-0": {
        "name": "DOC250618-25062018100132.pdf",
        "type": "application\/pdf",
        "tmp_name": "\/tmp\/phpZxLpb5",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 749634
    },
    "fileTwo-0": {
        "name": "Emirates ID.pdf",
        "type": "application\/pdf",
        "tmp_name": "\/tmp\/phpHHha5Y",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 0
    }
}
```

As you can see, for some reason the file size of `"fileTwo-0"` is 0 bytes.

This user then hit 'submit' again less than 20 seconds later and at this point both `"fileOne-0"` and `"fileTwo-0"` show a size of 0 bytes:

```
{
    "fileOne-0": {
        "name": "DOC250618-25062018100132.pdf",
        "type": "application\/pdf",
        "tmp_name": "\/tmp\/php425HN3",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 0
    },
    "fileTwo-0": {
        "name": "Emirates ID.pdf",
        "type": "application\/pdf",
        "tmp_name": "\/tmp\/phpjdaDHO",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 0
    }
}
```

Hence my assumption that regardless of the error on our part of not checking the file 'size' is greater that 0, there must be something happening between the browser and the JS code that is affecting the computed 'size' of the file that the user is uploading.

Here is the jQuery validate code for the form:

```
   $.validator.addMethod("emailRule", function (value, element) {
        return /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value);
    }, "- Your Email address is not in the correct format");

    $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
    });

   $("#form").validate({
        focusInvalid: false,
        errorContainer: "#validation-results",
        errorLabelContainer: "#validation-results",
        errorElement: "li",
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        groups: {
            fileGroup: "fileOne fileTwo fileThree fileFour"
        },
        rules: {
            fullName: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            emailAdd: {
                emailRule: true,
                maxlength: 80,
                required: true
            },
            accountNum: {
                minlength: 14,
                maxlength: 14,
                required: true
            },
            certify: {
                required: true
            },
            fileOne: {
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf",
                filesize: 3145728,
                require_from_group: [1, '.fileGroup']
            },
            fileTwo: {
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf",
                filesize: 3145728,
                require_from_group: [1, '.fileGroup']
            },
            fileThree: {
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf",
                filesize: 3145728,
                require_from_group: [1, '.fileGroup']
            },
            fileFour: {
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf",
                filesize: 3145728,
                require_from_group: [1, '.fileGroup']
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fullName: {
                required: jQuery.validator.format("- Please input your Full name as per Passport"),
                maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("- Please input your Full name as per Passport")
            },
            emailAdd: {
                required: jQuery.validator.format("- Please input your Email address"),
                email: jQuery.validator.format("- Your Email address is not in the correct format")
            },
            accountNum: {
                required: jQuery.validator.format("- Your Account number is not valid"),
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("- Your Account number is not valid"),
                maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("- Your Account number is not valid")
            },
            certify: {
                required: jQuery.validator.format("- Please acknowledge that the data you have provided is accurate")
            },
            fileOne: {
                require_from_group: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a supporting document"),
                accept: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload one of the valid document types"),
                filesize: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a file smaller than 3MB")
            },
            fileTwo: {
                require_from_group: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a supporting document"),
                accept: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload one of the valid document types"),
                filesize: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a file smaller than 3MB")
            },
            fileThree: {
                require_from_group: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a supporting document"),
                accept: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload one of the valid document types"),
                filesize: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a file smaller than 3MB")
            },
            fileFour: {
                require_from_group: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a supporting document"),
                accept: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload one of the valid document types"),
                filesize: jQuery.validator.format("- Please upload a file smaller than 3MB")
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            formData = new FormData(),
                params = $(form).serializeArray(),
                fileOne = $(form).find('[name="fileOne"]')[0].files,
                fileTwo = $(form).find('[name="fileTwo"]')[0].files,
                fileThree = $(form).find('[name="fileThree"]')[0].files,
                fileFour = $(form).find('[name="fileFour"]')[0].files;

            if (fileOne.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileOne, function (i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileOne-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            if (fileTwo.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileTwo, function (i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileTwo-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            if (fileThree.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileThree, function (i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileThree-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            if (fileFour.length != 0) {
                $.each(fileFour, function (i, file) {
                    formData.append('fileFour-' + i, file);
                });
            }

            $.each(params, function (i, val) {
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/process.php",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            }).done(function (response) {

                if (response == 'success') {
                    // window.location.replace('success.html');
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                    // window.location.replace('failure.html');
                }

            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {

                // window.location.replace('failure.html');
                console.log(error);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(textStatus);

            });
            return false;
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
                return;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("body").offset().top - 100
            }, 2000, function () {

                if ($("#fileOne").hasClass("error")) {
                    $("#fileOneContainer").addClass("error");
                } else {
                    $("#fileOneContainer").removeClass("error");
                }

                if ($("#fileTwo").hasClass("error")) {
                    $("#fileTwoContainer").addClass("error");
                } else {
                    $("#fileTwoContainer").removeClass("error");
                }

                if ($("#fileThree").hasClass("error")) {
                    $("#fileThreeContainer").addClass("error");
                } else {
                    $("#fileThreeContainer").removeClass("error");
                }

                if ($("#fileFour").hasClass("error")) {
                    $("#fileFourContainer").addClass("error");
                } else {
                    $("#fileFourContainer").removeClass("error");
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Some obvious things I will be doing is to add some validation in the JS to make sure the file is greater that 0 bytes and updating jQuery and jQuery validate to the latest versions.

Has anyone ever come across an issue like this before?

Comment: Why not just use `formData = new FormData(form)` and forget all the messing around you're doing with manually calling `append()` to the FormData? The only change is that you'd need to deal with an array of files on the server, but you should be doing this anyway

Comment: Thanks Rory, makes a lot of sense - to be fair I've inherited this project from another dev, not written it entirely myself, hence all that messing about.